# shouldn't col height in Bootstrap just cover the content unless mentioned otherwise?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am working on a code on the online training I am taking on bootstrap. I am following the exact steps as mentioned in the training but in my result the height of the row I am creating is much higher than it should be.

So the training is on Bootstrap 3, but I am using bootstrap 4 (in case that is important information). I create a row and then two columns each col-md-2 for img and then put images on them. But then the height of the columns are much higher than what it should be.

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="1" class="col-md-2" />
                    <img src="images/carousel-2.jpg" alt="2" class="col-md-2" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want the height of columns to be the size of the images with acceptable padding and margin, and not 3 to 4 times bigger.

Picture of my website:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also add class="img-responsive" to each img element. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

```
 <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-2">
                     <img src="images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="1"/>
                     <img src="images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```